# Scroll down the page, then up with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

Once I hit a button, I wanted the page to get to its lowest point and then back up. I think some sort of callback would be needed, but I can't define it. I report below the portion of the code concerned.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".home-button").on('click', function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          'scrollTop': $('footer').offset().top
        }, 1500);
        //then come back
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="home-button">Start</a>
    <!-- ... -->
    <footer><p>Stop and go back</p></footer>
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use setTimeout to go back after exactly the animation time!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let sameValue = 1500;
    $(".home-button").on('click', function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          'scrollTop': $('footer').offset().top
        }, sameValue );
        //then come back
        setTimeout(()=>{            $('html, body').animate({
          'scrollTop': $('.home-button').offset().top
        }, sameValue );},sameValue );
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="home-button">Start</a>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div style="height:700px;background-color:red;" ></div>
    <footer><p>Stop and go back</p></footer>
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are right on the `callback` part, just add another `animate` in the `callback` function to scroll back top.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".home-button").on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop': $('footer').offset().top
    }, 1500, 'swing', function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $('body').offset().top
      }, 1500);
    });
    //then come back
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <a class="home-button">Start</a>
  <!-- ... -->
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <footer>
    <p>Stop and go back</p>
  </footer>
</body>
<html>
```